# sqlalchemy - get number of entries that will be committed, dry run

Tags: sqlalchemy

I make a tool with [sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org) that copies entries from one base to another. I want to add "dry run" option, so instead of real committing, it would just print a number of entries that *would be* committed:

```
session.add(foo)
session.add(bar)
if dry_run:
    print session.number_of_items_to_commit # <-- should print "2"
else:
    session.commit()
```

How to get the number of items that are to be committed? I didn't see any appropriate method in [Session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) class.

Comment: [session.new](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.new) / [session.dirty](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.dirty) might be helpful

Comment: Works, thanks. Post is as an answer so I can flag it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably use [`len(session.new)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.new) for your task:

> The set of all instances marked as ‘new’ within this Session.

if you also need to track modified objects, use [session.dirty](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.dirty)